# Docker compose of flask-serial

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, docker-compose, pyserial

Hello I am new to docker and I try to dockerize my flask application.

When I sending message from virtual serial port, serial-message doesn't appear in index.html textarea. Here are my codes.

dockerfile

```py
LABEL Name=ise-4000 Version=0.0.1
EXPOSE 5555

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
COPY templates /app/templates

# Using pip:
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  ise-4000:
    image: ise-4000
    build: .
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
```

app.py

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mynameislaunglaung'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def session():
    return render_template('session.html')

def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print("message was received!!")

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('received my event: ', json)
    socketio.emit('my response', json, callback=messageReceived)

@socketio.on('cleint send message')
def handle_my_message(message):
    print("message data: ", message)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port='5555')
```

session.html

```html
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block title %}ISE-4000{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
{{ super() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
{{ super() }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);


    console.log(document.domain + ":" + location.port);
    socket.on('serial_message', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var text = data['message'];
      var $textarea = $('#serial_message');
      $textarea.val($textarea.val() + text + '\n');
    })
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Receive Serial Messages</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Messages:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <textarea id="serial_message" class="form-control" rows=10></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

My question is that virtual port is not working in docker container or something wrong in my code.

Comment: what if you try with `socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0'`

Comment: Yeah, I already tried with `host='0.0.0.0'`. Did I need to change docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Your code says the port is 9999... You're exposing only 5555

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry, I copy the wrong app.py file, I running the right port with 5555.

Comment: What about session.html as well? Your question says you're showing index.html... In any case, `socket.on('serial_message`, needs to map somehow to what Python is sending, but none of the strings there say `serial_message`

Comment: In other words, since you seem to think it's a problem with ports, did this code work outside of Docker?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, it works 100% and I though I needed to map serial port setting in docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: I guess my question then is, have you tried doing `emit('serial_message'`? I don't know much about SocketIO, but I have a hard time visualizing where/which messages are going where, but it seems nothing in your Python code emits an event on the channel named `serial_message`

Answer (score 0):

I'm just briefly looking at SocketIO documentation, but I think the issue is that your JS code is listening for a particular type of event named `"serial_message"`

```
socket.on('serial_message'
```

Yet, your Flask app never emits that message type, only `'my response'`

```
socketio.emit('my response'
```

These two strings must match if you want data to "flow" over the socket

---

Similarly, you put two `@socketio.on` annotations in the Python code, but nothing you've shown is emitting those event types (and you spelled client wrong)

---

And `methods=['GET', 'POST']` only is applicable for methods with a Flask route associated with them, not callbacks or socketio functions